# Puppeteer: page.screenshot Times Out

Tags: puppeteer

I have a seemingly simple problem with Puppeteer: when I try to take a screenshot, like so ...

```
console.log(1)
await page.screenshot({ path: 'screenshot.png' });
console.log(2)
```

Puppeteer hangs.  It doesn't error out or anything, it just waits forever (logging "1" but not "2"), until the whole test times out.

I'm not sure how to resolve this, as `screenshot` doesn't even have a `timeout` option I can use to force it to timeout faster (as many other Puppeteer functions do). Can anyone suggest:

A) any conditions that would cause this (eg. could I somehow be on a page that failed to load, or something like that)?

B) how I can get `screenshot` to take the screenshot, or at least throw an error if it can't?

Comment: Could you share a [mcve] please? I can't reproduce the problem with just this code here. Which version of Puppeteer are you using? Thanks.

Comment: It's really that simple, and I'm not sure how a repro would help, as I can't share my whole site that the test is running against.  Before that, I was just waiting for a submit button to appear, and then I clicked it (and before that I filled out a form) ... that's it.  Something might be going wrong with that click, but I can't see what because I can't take a screenshot.  I was just hoping someone could speak, in general terms, to *anything* that would make `screenshot` time out.

Comment: BTW, if I do the screenshot just before the `await page.click(selector, { timeout: 2000 });`  line, it  *doesn't* time out.  So it does seem to be related to the click somehow ... but I can `console.log` after the click, so the click itself isn't timing out.  I have no idea why a click would make a screenshot timeout (without an error).

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the site or environment details. If I run this on any site I know of, it works fine, so there's really no way to help here without more information. So the click _does_ matter but isn't in your code. Still not reproducible, but important.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I'm still hoping *someone* who has worked with Puppeteer before might know of *anything* that can make `screenshot` time out.  Even if it's not the same case as mine, it would help me understand what makes `screenshot` time out (instead of erroring out).

Comment: Could you at least share a Puppeteer version? There are bugs that sometimes get deployed, so changing to a different version may also help you determine if that's the case. You can also try running it on other sites to establish that the site is the cause. Thanks.

Comment: `"puppeteer": "^19.7.2"`  Also I looked "under the hood" to try and understand things better, but saw that Pupeteer's screenshot function basically just wraps a similar function in the dev tools (which unfortunatelty is a dead-end, as I'm not reading the Chrome source).  I also found https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2117, which suggested manually timing out `screenshot`, and then calling it again a few seconds later ... but that didn't work either :(

Comment: Thanks. So if you downgrade to, say, Pupp 13.x, the same problem occurs? And on other websites, the same problem occurs with the same code? That GH issue looks pretty relevant, nice find, although no apparent cause or repro, other than maybe docker for one commenter.

Comment: Well, I found the problem, so I'm not sure how useful it will be to downgrade.  But thank you so much for all your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did what I should have done from the start, and retried doing what my test was doing manually. When I did, I noticed that just before the screenshot was taken, my site was doing a plain old `window.alert`.

As soon as I commented that `alert` out, the screenshot worked successfully!

So, for future reference: if your `page.screenshot` is timing out, check for any `alert`s (or, presumably, `confirm`s or `prompt`s), as apparently Puppeteer can't handle taking a screenshot of one of the web's oldest UI features.

P.S. I filed https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/9801, so hopefully it will get fixed and I can delete this question/answer.

Comment: Again, there's no way I could put the entire site (or even page) I was testing into a repro (and when I started out, I had no idea the `alert` was the problem, so I never would have though to repro just it).  And whether it was dumb or not, it's a completely undocumented failure of Puppeteer, which again others might want to know about.

Comment: You can't share the URL of the page you're manipulating?

Comment: I can't :( It's behind a login wall, and ATM the live site doesn't even have this page.

Comment: OK, well glad you worked it out and thanks for self-answering. The problem with alerts is that they lock the JS thread, so I don't think this is a Puppeteer flaw as much as you may suggest.